# Nesting options under an if binding causes wrong behavior

Tags: html, knockout.js

I want to have a `<select>` without using the `options` binding, and nest the `<option>` element under an `if` binding.

The following is what I did (here's also a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4vdfyde/3/)), which displays a behavior I wasn't expecting: The `if` seems to fire for each option selection, whereas what I expected is that it would fire only when adding the options elements to DOM.

Thus, when an option is chosen, it doesn't displayed. Only when choosing the same option again, it renders as it should.

What did I do wrong?

```js
var DogHouseViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.allowedNames = ["A", "B", "C"];
    self.puppies = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.createPuppy = function () {
      self.puppies.push(new DogViewModel());
    }
    self.isNameAlreadyTaken = function (puppyName) {
      var puppies = self.puppies();
      for (var i = 0; i < puppies.length; i++) {
        if (puppies[i].dogName() == puppyName) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
    self.printPuppiesName = function () {
     self.puppies().forEach(function (puppy) {
       alert(puppy.dogName())
    })
  }
}

var DogViewModel = function (dogName) {
   var self = this;
   self.dogName = ko.observable();
}

vm = new DogHouseViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>  
   <button data-bind="text: 'create a puppy', click: createPuppy"></button>
   <button data-bind="text: 'print puppies names', click: printPuppiesName"></button>
   <div data-bind="foreach: puppies">
      <select data-bind="value: dogName">
         <!-- ko foreach: $parent.allowedNames -->
            <!-- ko if: !($root.isNameAlreadyTaken($data)) -->
               <option data-bind="value: $data, text: $data"></option> 
            <!-- /ko -->
         <!-- /ko -->
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The behavior I get is that the select displays A after I select B or C, but when I "print puppies names", it shows the selected values in the alert.

Comment: @RoyJ, right, that's indeed what happens. I'm trying to understand why it keeps displaying A.

Comment: I can't explain the behavior; I'd have to say it's buggy and related to the `if` causing updates. The solution would be to make a computed that generates the options list you want and use that with the options binding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do. The problem is that your allowedNames are the values of the options do you can't just remove them from the array. But you can clone the parent array and as it changes compute the array by returning a list of not used values.

I also added a check to make sure we don't accidentally add a puppy object to the puppies array when no names are available.

```js
var DogHouseViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.allowedNames = ["A", "B", "C"];
  self.puppies = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.createPuppy = function() {
    var newPuppy = new DogViewModel(self);
    if(newPuppy.allowedNames().length > 0) { // Check to see if there are any names left.   
      self.puppies.push(newPuppy);
    }
  }
  self.removePuppy = function(obj) {
    self.puppies.remove(obj);
  }

  self.printPuppiesName = function() {
    self.puppies().forEach(function(puppy) {
      alert(puppy.dogName())
    })
  }
}

var DogViewModel = function(parent) {
  var self = this;
  self.dogName = ko.observable();
  self.allowedNames = ko.computed(function() {
    var allowedNamesClone = parent.allowedNames.slice(0);
    var usedNames = parent.puppies().filter(function(pup) { // get all pups who have a name
      return pup.dogName() !== '' && pup.dogName() !== self.dogName();
    })
    usedNames.forEach(function(pup) {
      var index = allowedNamesClone.indexOf(pup.dogName());
      if (index > -1) {
        allowedNamesClone.splice(index, 1); // remove name from cloned array
      }
    })
    return allowedNamesClone; // return new array
  })
}

vm = new DogHouseViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button data-bind="text: 'create a puppy', click: createPuppy"></button>
  <button data-bind="text: 'print puppies names', click: printPuppiesName"></button>
  <div data-bind="foreach: puppies">
    <!-- ko if: allowedNames().length > 0 -->
    <select data-bind="options: allowedNames, value: dogName"></select>
    <button data-bind="click: $root.removePuppy">x</button>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
</div>
```